# Ncurses CTRL + s hangs getch()

Tags: c++, ncurses

Why in this simple program:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    timeout(-1);
    int c = getch();
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    endwin();
}
```

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> hangs it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start curses using [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization), the terminal is in *cooked mode*, which honors XON/XOFF.  In the curses manual pages, that is referred to as *"flow control characters"*; [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html) refers to it as *"output control"*:

```
IXON
    Enable start/stop output control.
```

If you call [`raw`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-raw_noraw), that turns XON/XOFF ***off***, and you can use <kbd>*control*</kbd>**`S`**:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    initscr();
    raw(); // possibly what you intended
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    timeout(-1);
    int c = getch();
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    endwin();
}
```

Your application could call `tcgetattr` to determine if the underlying XON/XOFF mode is set, but that would not help in determining if curses has raw-mode set:

- curses always sets the terminal to raw mode,
- curses simulates cooked/raw mode for your application, and
- curses has no function that your application could call to find the current state.

Comment: Is there a way to honor signals handling routines in raw mode? I need to ignore ctrl+s but allow ctrl+c. Thanks

Comment: Use [`cbreak`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak) rather than `raw`, then.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're experiencing [XOFF/XON flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is XOFF, and stops output until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> (XON) is sent. You can probably resume your program by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

This is not an issue with your code. It's happening at the terminal level.

Comment: Is there any way to know that ctrl+s was pressed?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.